# TileServer GL : issue with port 8080

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, openmaptiles, tileserver-gl

This is the current situation :

```
root@vmi1046457:~# sudo docker run --restart=always -it -d -v 
/root/openmaptiles/data:/data -p 8080:80 maptiler/tileserver-gl
9cfafc58933b3e8080c27b92463d276d1c46b718d28a59665a8cb5a945ebb905

root@vmi1046457:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                         PORTS                            NAMES
9cfafc58933b   maptiler/tileserver-gl   "/usr/src/app/docker…"   2 hours ago   Up 2    
hours (healthy)   8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   dazzling_colden



root@vmi1046457:~# sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp
Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)

root@vmi1046457:~# nc -l -p 8080 
nc: Address already in use
root@vmi1046457:~# 

 root@vmi1046457:~# netstat -an|grep LIST 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42069         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     722894   /run/user/0/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     722900   /run/user/0/bus
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     722902   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.dirmngr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     722904   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     722906   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21766    /var/run/docker/libnetwork/314b586c6194.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     722908   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     722910   /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2392     /run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2394     /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2396     /run/docker.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2398     /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18003    /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18005    /run/systemd/userdb/io.systemd.DynamicUser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18006    /run/systemd/io.system.ManagedOOM
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18025    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     18028    /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     24635    /run/irqbalance/irqbalance509.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     19343    /run/systemd/journal/io.systemd.journal
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     24666    /run/systemd/resolve/io.systemd.Resolve
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4612     /run/containerd/containerd.sock.ttrpc
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4614     /run/containerd/containerd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18235    /var/run/docker/metrics.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2431     /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     795125   /run/containerd/s/dcb7b80af05b61e4b240a5af6588e095dab23ace3a0f87274e50fb6289c889c7


root@vmi1046457:~# sudo nmap 194.x.x.x
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-11-23 11:08 CET
Nmap scan report for vmi1046457.contaboserver.net (194.60.201.224)
Host is up (0.000062s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   open     http
8080/tcp filtered http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.41 seconds
root@vmi1046457:~# sudo ufw enable^C
root@vmi1046457:~# 
root@vmi1046457:~# 
root@vmi1046457:~# 
root@vmi1046457:~# sudo netstat -plant | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      188808/docker-proxy
```

If I put in the browser address bar: http://194.x.x.x/ -> I correctly get:

```
Apache2 Default Page
```

If If put: http://194.x.x.x:8080/ -> I get :

```
This site can’t be reached194.x.x.x refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
```

And:

```
root@vmi1046457:~# curl 194.x.x.x
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 194.x.x.x port 8080 after 22 ms: Connection refused
```

What should I do in order to be able to connect to `194.x.x.x:8080` ?

Answer (score 2):

I changed from `8080:80` to `8080:8080` ( a brand new change in `tileserver-gl` settings)

```
root@vmi1046457:~# sudo docker run --restart=always -it -d -v /root/openmaptiles/data:/data -p 8080:8080 maptiler/tileserver-gl
3219b5dcd97a182b101a6fa06f05eefb13e7f0b573b58b3ce4ffe9394d4469ee
root@vmi1046457:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                            PORTS                    NAMES
3219b5dcd97a   maptiler/tileserver-gl   "/usr/src/app/docker…"   9 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   adoring_shamir
root@vmi1046457:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                             PORTS                    NAMES
3219b5dcd97a   maptiler/tileserver-gl   "/usr/src/app/docker…"   35 seconds ago   Up 28 seconds (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   adoring_shamir
root@vmi1046457:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                        PORTS                    NAMES
3219b5dcd97a   maptiler/tileserver-gl   "/usr/src/app/docker…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   adoring_shamir
root@vmi1046457:~#
```

and now it works fine

Comment: Are you currently running on ubuntu? I have had issues in the past where apache2 automatically boots and then will occupy that port from startup. You need to stop apache and your original port usage may work. Not certain though

Comment: Hi @Buzzkillionair ! Yes. Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Try using this command in your command prompt ```sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop``` @Raphael10